# Why is this .htacess file is not working?

Tags: .htaccess, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to redirect non-www to www URL’s using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157255/how-to-redirect-non-www-to-www-urls-using-htaccess)

My htaccess file is doing nothing although I am adding folloeing code in it.(I think it is not enable)

My current website address is like that **www.abc.com/mvc/view/index.php**

And the new address is **www.abc.com/index.php**

My hosting provider is godaddy.com. and there is also PHP.ini file in the same  directory  I have placed htaccess file in the root directory seems like  html/.httaccess.The complete  htaccess file is like

```
Redirect /mvc/view/index.php http://abc.com
```

But its not working.I am confused about .htacces file placement and also the rewrite code line. Can you please help me out?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? It isn't generating the correct HTTP headers? It's triggering an error message?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) looks correct. Please note that you need to have a `FileInfo` permission:

> **Description:**  Sends an external redirect asking the client to fetch a different URL
>   **Syntax:**   Redirect [status] URL-path URL
>   **Context:**  server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
>   **[Override:](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/directive-dict.html#Override)**    FileInfo

You should ask your hosting provider whether you're allowed to use this directive.